# Is `p` in the formula for adjusted R-square defined for tree models?

Tags: regression, cart, r-squared, definition, degrees-of-freedom

Let $R^2$ be the R-squared defined for regression models. Given a vector `x`, the target, and a vector, `y`, the prediction of the same length, then we can compute $R$.

However, there is also the adjusted $R^2$ (see formula below) which adds $n$ and $p$ where $n$ is the number of rows and $p$ the number of features in the modelling data.

[image]

However, even though we can compute $R^2$ for a tree-based model, I think $p$ is not defined in the case of a tree model. Hence adjusted $R^2$ doesn't make sense for a tree-based model.

Is this correct?

Comment: $R^2$ is in fact quite problematic for nonlinear models. Search this Stack for the details, but the gist is that the predictions and residuals are not orthogonal in nonlinear models. Anyway, I don’t see a way to make $p$ make sense, but the point of adjusted $R^2$ is to do inference. If you’re using a tree (I’m really thinking RF), your goal is to predict, not to do inference.

Answer (score 1):

It is often said on this site that R-squared is problematic for nonlinear models, search ... , but I cannot find a canonic thread. A published paper, with simulations, is [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2892436/), and they also point to information measures like AIC as better alternatives.   From an answer in [this R-help thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2002-July/023461.html)

> There is a good reason that an nls model fit in R does not provide
>   r-squared - r-squared doesn't make sense for a general nls model.
>
> One way of thinking of r-squared is as a comparison of the residual
>   sum of squares for the fitted model to the residual sum of squares for
>   a trivial model that consists of a constant only.  You cannot
>   guarantee that this is a comparison of nested models when dealing with
>   an nls model.  If the models aren't nested this comparison is not
>   terribly meaningful.
>
> So the answer is that you probably don't want to do this in the first
>   place.

-- Douglas Bates

(This would apply equally to the adjusted version.) But that answer also points to a solution: R-squared is a kind of *comparison to a simple, default (and nested) model*, and if you can find some *other* simple model for comparison, you can use that. But, for a regression tree, the constant only model corresponds to a default tree with only one node, the root, so R-squared do make sense in this case.

But your question about the *meaning of $p$* (the number of parameters) for a tree model is still interesting! In models like splines, gams and many others, we use a measure called *the effective number of parameters* or *effective number of degrees of freedom*. See [this list of questions with answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=effective+degrees+of+freedom++answers%3A1).  But can this be defined for a very non-linear model like trees (or forests?) The book *The Elements of Statistical Learning* by Hastie, Tibshirani & Friedman offers a discussion as Exercise 9.5 (page 336, second Edition.) What is proposed there is to define the degrees of freedom of the fit as $\DeclareMathOperator{\C}{\mathbb{Cov}} \sum_i \C(y_i, \hat{y}_i)/\sigma^2$. Doing the exercise is left for you.  It should involve some simulation.

Some related posts:  [Decision Tree Quality Metric](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/280209/decision-tree-quality-metric),  [computing AIC or BIC for nonlinear regression models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/347773/computing-aic-or-bic-for-nonlinear-regression-models)